# Authenticate Steam OAuth with Firebase | Golang

Tags: authentication, go, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am developing a website in Golang and need to authenticate each user so only they can read their own firebase user information.

I'm using Firebase V3 and the [firego](https://github.com/zabawaba99/firego/) package for golang. I've tried using the [fireauth](https://github.com/zabawaba99/fireauth/) package to authenticate a user with a generated token, but this package only supports Firebase V2.

How can I authenticate my users with Firebase 3 when they login through [Steam's OAuth/OpenID](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/) on my website in Golang?

---

I've tried using the [JWT](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/) package for Golang to generate a token then send it to the user to use `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)` to authenticate but I didn't manage to generate the token.

Here is the code I used to generate with JWT:

```
jwtToken := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
    "uid": "172346362",
})

signKey, err := jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM([]byte(`I don't know what to put here,
                                                      I tried a number of things including
                                                      randomly generated private RSA keys`))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

token, err := jwtToken.SignedString(signKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

if err := tmpl.Execute(w, token); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I recieve the following error message when using this code:

```
Invalid Key: Key must be PEM encoded PKCS1 or PKCS8 private key
```

Comment: I used https://github.com/zabawaba99/fireauth/issues/9 to write the JWT code but it didn't quite work for me.

Comment: godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#example-New--Hmac I have had this issue for the whole day. I am trying to use the exact code in the link, but what do I use for the hmacSampleSecret? It's been puzzling me for so long.